# JS import - VueJs Router - having trouble refactoring a watch object

Tags: ecmascript-6, vue.js

This question is specific to vuejs router, however may simply be a misunderstanding of importing js objects and assigning to the window object.

I am watching for url changes on a page which works fine with the watcher code in the component file. I need to use the same watcher code for multiple components so I extracted it to its own file, assigned it to the global scope, and cannot get it to work. Here are the details:

Working code in with the watcher in the component:

```
 watch:{
            $route () {
                console.log('route changed')
                //was it a reset?

                console.log( this.$route.query.sort)

                if(this.$route.query.sort === undefined){
                    if(this.$route.meta.reset){
                        //reset was pressed... actually do nothing here
                        this.$route.meta['reset'] = false;
                    }
                    else{
                        this.loading = true;
                        this.searchableTable.removeResultsTable();
                        this.searchableTable.options.search_query = this.$route.fullPath;
                        this.searchableTable.updateSearchPage();
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    //sort change just update the table view
                }





            }
        }
```

So then I extracted the watch to a file routeWatcher.js:

```
export default  {
    $route () {
        console.log('route changed')
        //was it a reset?

        console.log(this.$route.query.sort)

        if (this.$route.query.sort === undefined) {
            if (this.$route.meta.reset) {
                //reset was pressed... actually do nothing here
                this.$route.meta['reset'] = false;
            }
            else {
                this.loading = true;
                this.searchableTable.removeResultsTable();
                this.searchableTable.options.search_query = this.$route.fullPath;
                this.searchableTable.updateSearchPage();
            }

        }
        else {
            //sort change just update the table view
        }


    }

}
```

then I import and use, which works fine....

```
import searchableTableRouteWatcher from '../../controllers/routeWatcher'
```

...

```
watch:searchableTableRouteWatcher
```

again works fine.

Now the problem -  I want to avoid the import in multiple files, so I thought I could put it on the window as a global

in my main.js file:

```
import searchableTableRouteWatcher from './controllers/routeWatcher'
window.searchableTableRouteWatcher = searchableTableRouteWatcher;
```

Then in my component:

```
watch:searchableTableRouteWatcher
```

results in searchableTableRouteWatcher is not defined

```
watch:window.searchableTableRouteWatcher
```

results in no errors, but the code is not being called

I have a feeling it has to do with `this` and there is confusion on `$route()`

Comment: Coudl you console log `this` into the $route method in the `routeWatcher.js`

Comment: No, the code is not executing... there is a log in there I am not receiving

Answer (score 0):

For your purpose there are 'Mixins' in Vue.js: [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html)

What you can do:

create a file, say mixins/index.js:

```
export const routeWatcher = {
   watch: {... your watcher code pasted here ... }
};
```

import into your component:

```
import { routeWatcher } from 'path/to/mixins/index';
```

add mixin to your component properties and methods:

```
<script>
   export default {
       mixins: [routeWatcher];
       data () ...... all your original component's script content
   }
```

Mixin's content will be merged with component's original properties and act if it was hardcoded there.

**Addition after your comment:**

You can also declare Mixin globally, like this:

above 'new Vue' declaration put this code:

```
Vue.mixin({
   watch: {....}
});
```

This mixin will appear in every component.

Comment: Ok that is sweet, I will update to using a mixin, thanks for that! However do I need the import in each component? Can I / should I assign mixin to a global? i.e. stick it on the window object then reference it in the component without an import... that is actually where I was stuck, I can import the mixin on each component, but I can't seem to do it globally, where I have a ton of other globals no problem...

Comment: Added global declaration to my answer.

Comment: Sorry, not globally on vue. I need to use the mixin on 20+ components, but not all of them. I was trying to avoid 20 import statements, in case I needed to change the file, which based on our discussion of mixins, I will be changing the file. Rather than changing 20 imports, I would want to change one import when I am bootstrapping, and assign the mixin to a global variable like window.mixin1 = mixin1, then use mixin:mixin1 on the component that needs it. That is where I am stuck